# Android : Bundle Vs Intent

Tags: java, android

I'm able to pass String (which is an object) to another activity through intent. But whenever I tried to pass some other class object (eg: "LatLng" class object) through intent to another activity, seeing runtime errors. What is the difference between sting object and LatLng class object in this context?

Note:  I'm able to pass LatLng class object through bundle without any issues, but I just wanted to know the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass all the primitive type values in Intent as it is, like String, int, boolean etc. In case of String type by default it implements `Serializable`.

```
public final class
String
extends Object
implements Serializable CharSequence Comparable<T>
```

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html)

But if you have a complex object that you want to pass inside a Bundle either you have to make it `Serializable` or `Parcelable`. Since `Serializable` is java native implementation and it was not designed for Portable devices like Mobile. So if you really consider about performance you have to use `Parcelable` instead. Google itself promote the use of `Parcelable`.

But in your case [LatLng](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.html) implements Parcelable. So you can use

[putParcelable(String key, Parcelable value)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelable%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable%29)

And to access this use below method.

[public T getParcelable (String key);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getParcelable%28java.lang.String%29)